# Notes not appearing on PDF when reopened

Tags: pdf, preview, notes.app

I bought my first MacBook Air and am having trouble with the Preview app.

I am reading a PDF and have highlighted some important phrases and added notes(or memos) for future references.

So here is what I did. I first highlighted the phrase then right click on the highlighted phrase to add a note(or memo). Then on the right top corner 'Yellow Square' appears where the square enlarges when clicked and notes can be written on.

The problem is yellow squares at the right top corner all disappear when I reopen the PDF (even after saving the document!!!)and I'm not able to access the full text in the note I have added previously.

I am aware that from left top corner I can select 'Highlights&Memos' to access all the highlighted parts and memos. But from the left sidebar I can only see small bit of my notes and not the full text.

No matter I click the highlighted phrase or notes on the left side bar nothing happens. I just can't get the note to open in full size.

I haven't changed any settings. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
I want my 'Yellow Squares' to reappear where it originally appeared!

Comment: Can you supply a sample document?